# Node.js: Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js

I get an error from my Node.js application:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:559:19)
```

I think I can catch this error by calling `.on('error', function () {...})` on some object, but how can I find out on which object?

Comment: Are you triying to use port 80 on linux? If that so you have to be admin

Answer (score 0):

It's one of your TCP connections, but you are right that due to the short stack traces of an event loop, it can be a mystery to figure out. Even then, the intermediate libraries may not give convenient access to the actual connection instance that is the source of the error. If you just want to catch the error, `process.onUncaughtException` will give you a last resort mechanism to do so. You may also want to try Domains and see if they at least help you track down the source (as they will maintain a causal chain for you). There are also some long stack trace modules on npm that might help.

You may also have to start dividing your program into smaller parts to isolate the subsystem involved.